# Laravel - returning SSH output

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, ssh

Thanks for interest to this topic. I'm pretty new in **Laravel** and i have a little question. Maybe it's easy!
I have an SSH module in my Laravel that works this way:
The user fills the textarea element with Linux commands.
**The command is passed with Ajax to a method called getExecute() located in the 'controllers' folder**
I would like that this method returns me the full response of my SSH server, but this isn't happening. The only thing that the method returns is a blank space.

**For example:** I pass the command 'ls -la', and my response is all folders that the Linux find, like on terminal.
Can someone help me please?
Here is my code:

```
public function getExecute()
{
    if(\Request::ajax()):

        $ssh_command = \Input::get('ssh_command');
        $ssh_response = null;

        \SSH::run($ssh_command, function($line)
        {
            return $line.PHP_EOL;
        });

    endif;
}
```

OBS: The Ajax connection was tested and it's ok!
Thank you!

Comment: It's generally more preferred that you put the solution, even if you are the one answered, as an answer and mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: Thanks Unnawut, i'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally solved! Solution below:**

First i've created a variable called $output in my class.

```
private $output;
```

Then i modified my method to this:

```
public function postExecute()
{
    $ssh_command = \Input::get('ssh_command');
    $ssh_response = \SSH::run($ssh_command, function($line)
    {
        $this->output = $line.PHP_EOL;
    });

    return $this->output;
}
```

**My method is not more Ajax**, but i hope that all that i have to do is rollback to my ajax method like before.Thanks for all!